# Javascript/jQuery event doesn't work on Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form that has 3 drop-down menus in which the options of the Sections drop-down will change dependent on the Grades dropdown selected by the user. I used **MYSQL** to query the sections needed for my section drop-down and onChange event from jQuery to do the thing I want. In my laptop's browser, it works perfectly without any error but when I tried it on a mobile browser both Android and iOS nothing works.

What happens: Is that when I select any of the Grades in the drop-down, all Sections will come out as an option in the Sections drop-down.

What I want to happen: When I select the Grade 12 option in the Grades' drop-down, the options in the Section drop-down should be Sections that have a gradelevel_id on it. This only works on PC/Laptop browser, not on the Mobile browser.

Here is the form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="markAttendance.php" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="gradelvl">Grade Level</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select id="gradelvl" name="glevel" class="form-control" required="">
                                      <option value=""></option>
                                      <option value="G1">Grade 1</option>
                                      <option value="G2">Grade 2</option>
                                      <option value="G3">Grade 3</option>
                                      <option value="G4">Grade 4</option>
                                      <option value="G5">Grade 5</option>
                                      <option value="G6">Grade 6</option>
                                      <option value="H1">Grade 7</option>
                                      <option value="H2">Grade 8</option>
                                      <option value="H3">Grade 9</option>
                                      <option value="H4">Grade 10</option>
                                      <option value="S1">Grade 11</option>
                                      <option value="S2">Grade 12</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sect">Section</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select id="sect" name="section" class="form-control" required="">
                                    <option data-group='SHOW' value=""></option>
                                        <?php 
                                        $secResult = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tbl_section") or die(mysql_error());

                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($secResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                        ?>
                                        <option data-group='<?php echo $row['gradeLevel_id'];?>' value='<?php echo $row['section_id'];?>'><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
                                        <?php }?>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <select id="subject" name="subj" class="form-control" required="">
                                      <option value=""></option>
                                        <?php 
                                        $tid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                                        $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT tbl_subjteachers.*, tbl_subject.title FROM tbl_subjteachers, tbl_subject WHERE tbl_subjteachers.subj_id = tbl_subject.subject_id AND tbl_subjteachers.teacher_id = '$tid'") or die(mysql_error());

                                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                        ?>
                                        <option value='<?php echo $row['subj_id'];?>'><?php echo $row['title'];?></option>
                                        <?php }?>                                          
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <center>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button id="signup" class="btn btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </center>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
```

And here is the script:

```
<script src="../../scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#gradelvl').on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var sub = $('#sect');
            $('option', sub).filter(function() {
                if (
                    $(this).attr('data-group') === val ||
                    $(this).attr('data-group') === 'SHOW'
                ) {
                    $(this).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            });
        });
        $('#gradelvl').trigger('change');
    });

</script>
```

What do you think is the problem? Also, Chart.js won't render on my mobile browser but it renders on my PC/Laptop.

Information that might help: I am using XAMPP and changed my localhost to a custom domain.